# How would I prove this conditional statement using a contrapositive method?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Original statement is  if  $x$  and  $y$  are   positive, then $$\sqrt{x + y}  \neq \sqrt{x} +  \sqrt{y}$$

And the contrapositive of this statement would be if  $$\sqrt{x + y} = \sqrt{x} +  \sqrt{y}$$ then, $x$ and $y$ are negative.

Comment: U guys are so smart man good job

Answer (score 2):

Original statement: If $x$ and $y$ are both positive, then $\sqrt{x + y} \neq \sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y}$.

The contrapositive of an implication $p \implies q$ is $\neg q \implies \neg p$.

In our case, this means that the contrapositive of the original statement is "If $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{x + y},$ then at least one of $x$ and $y$ are not positive."

Suppose we had $\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{x + y}$. Squaring each side, we obtain

$$ \Longleftrightarrow (\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{y})^{2} = (\sqrt{x + y})^{2} $$
$$\Longleftrightarrow x + 2\sqrt{xy} + y =  x + y$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow 2\sqrt{xy} = 0 $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{xy} = 0 $$

$$\Longleftrightarrow xy = 0. $$

But, the above equality $xy = 0$ can only be true if at least one of $x, y$ are equal to $0$ (which is not positive). So, by contrapositive, we are done.

Answer (score 0):

you state that if x,y are positive (x^2+y^2)^0.5 is not equal to x^0.5+y^0.5 
assume that it is equal,then this also would be true  x+y=x+y-2xy(just square both sides)   but this wrong (0is not equal to 2xy,if x,y are positive)that means our assumption was wrong which proves the statement